# Apache 2.4.10 mod_deflate small response size not compressed

Tags: php, apache, gzip, mod-deflate

I updated apache from version 2.2 to 2.4 some time ago and now all responses are not compressed anymore by mod_deflate. The limit seems to be 68 bytes. I tried to find some setting for this but could not find anything - is it even configurable?

Example:

```
echo "hellooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo" > /var/www/html/index.html
```

Response is not gzipped:

```
Content-Length: 68
```

After adding one more character:

```
echo "helloooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo" > /var/www/html/index.html
```

The response headers are ok and the content is compressed

```
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 28
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can force gzip output in PHP by using

`ob_start( "ob_gzhandler" );`

[php.net ob_gzhandler](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-gzhandler.php)